# hash map and arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

look at this small example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Foo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> foo = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        array.add(i);

    foo.put("1", array);
    // array.clear();

    System.out.println(foo.get("1").size());
 }
}
```

Now, if use `array.clear()` ***it automatically delete all values of the arrayList associated with the specified key inside the hashmap***

**how can I prevent this?**

in such a way that:

- I can perform `array.clear();` (after entering values ​​in hashmap) and only delete the values of `ArrayList<Integer> array`
- The values ,​​of the array associated with that key, won't  deleted **inside the hashmap**

if you launch this program,it will print **20** without using `array.clear();`, **0** instead

Comment: Are you sure you understand that java uses references to objects everywhere? If you store reference to array in HashMap then it is the same object as the one your local variable refers to.

Comment: in your hashmap declaration you are giving the reference to the same object so it is obvious that it will get deleted from both places(well clearly it does not exist at two places only one array exists), you use ONE array in TWO places.as @Andrey said please go through how java uses references to objects to understand it better.

Comment: CiMat, see my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is deleting the maps keys elements because both are same objects. You have to make a shallow copy to make both lists separate

Creating a shallow copy is pretty easy though:

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(oldList);
```

Here is the code:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> foo = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            array.add(i);

        ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(array);

        foo.put("1", newList);
        array.clear();

        System.out.println(foo.get("1").size());
    }

}
```

Comment: the only way is to to clone the elements? is there a pretty way than this?

Comment: no this is the only way to do that.. either copy arraylist

Comment: Actually he needs shallow clone. Deep clone means copy the objects in array themselves.

Comment: have changed the answer.. :) this will work in your case since both are diff arraylist

Comment: @niiraj874u just saw it.

Answer (score 2):

`foo.get("1")` and `array` refer to the same object. You need `foo.put("1", new ArrayList<Integer>(array));`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put not the ArrayList itself, but it's copy:

```
foo.put("1", new ArrayList<Integer>(array));
```

If you want to put the array itself, you must have it unmodifiable:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> foo = ...;
...
List<Integer> unmodifiableArray = Collections.unmodifiableList(array);
foo.put(unmodifiableArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you do not write "new" objects into that map. In other words
your list named "array", it's exactly the same memory address as that list in a map, so... if you change 1, changes appear in both places.